# Return JSON results = array values > count duplicate values and write to list item element

Tags: javascript, rest, api, for-loop

Problem Set: 
1. Pulling list data from List using REST API
2. Count number of items in results array (data.d.results)
3. Look for duplicate values within specific column and count occurrences (column name is 'Status')
4. Write number of occurrences to unique id list item elements

Successes thus far:
1. Returning results from API
2. Counting number of list items: data.d.results.length
3.

What works:

```
        $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){
            document.getElementById('ECP_Total_Count').innerHTML = data.d.results.length;
            if (item.STATUS == 'Draft') {count1++;}
            if (item.STATUS == 'Submitted') {count2++;} 
            if (item.STATUS == 'In Review') {count3++;}
            if (item.STATUS == 'Approved') {count4++;}
            if (item.STATUS == 'Deferred') {count5++;}
            if (item.STATUS == 'Rejected') {count6++;}
        })
        document.getElementById('ECPDraft').innerHTML = count1;
        document.getElementById('ECPSubmitted').innerHTML = count2;
        document.getElementById('ECPInReview').innerHTML = count3;
        document.getElementById('ECPApproved').innerHTML = count4;
        document.getElementById('ECPDeferred').innerHTML = count5;
        document.getElementById('ECPRejected').innerHTML = count6;
```

More efficient method needed:

```
            $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){
            var statusArray = ['Draft','Submitted','In Review','Approved','Deferred','Rejected'];
            var count1 = 0; var count2 = 0; var count3 = 0; var count4 = 0; var count5 = 0; var count6 = 0;
            document.getElementById('RFV_Total_Count').innerHTML = data.d.results.length;
            for (i = 0; i < statusArray.length; i++) {
                if (item.STATUS == statusArray[i]) {
                    count[i]++;
                    document.getElementById("RFV" + statusArray[i]).innerHTML = count[i];
                }
            }
```

I am looking to use a For loop instead of hard coding each iteration of count++ and also loop through the creation of getElementById method assigning the respective value from count1++, count2++... to each li element.

I hope this makes sense. I can try and reword if necessary. Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Whenever you find yourself working with a set of variables with names like `count1`, `count2`, and so on, consider instead working with an **array**.

Comment: I have. count1 and so on are variable not text values. If you have an example of an array with variables that can hold numbered values... something like [count1 : 0; count 2 : 0...] it throws an error for me

Comment: That doesn't make sense. An array `var count = []` would let you use `count[0]`, `count[1]`, etc just like variables, plus you could then use *another* variable as the index value.

Answer (score 0):

How about using an array of status Objects instead:

```
$.each(data.d.results, function(index, item){
    var statusArray = [
       {status: "Draft", count: 0},
       {status: "Submitted", count: 0},
       {status: "In Review", count: 0},
       {status: "Approved", count: 0},
       {status: "Deferred", count: 0},
       {status: "Rejected",, count: 0}
    ];
    document.getElementById('RFV_Total_Count').innerHTML = data.d.results.length;

    statusArray.forEach(function(stsObj){
         if(stsObj.status === item.STATUS){
             document.getElementById("RFV" + stsObj.status).innerHTML = ++stsObj.count;
         }
    });
}
```